# bootstrap-select default styling seems incorrect

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, bootstrap-select

I am using the awesome [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) jQuery plugin, but there are two odd default styles that are occurring.  After loading the relevant CSS and JS files into my website, This is the default styling that occurs for ALL my selectboxes (without updating my select boxes at all with any sort of attributes).

[image: default styling]

**Environment**

- Wordpress: 5.2.2
- Theme: [WP Bootstrap Starter](https://wordpress.org/themes/wp-bootstrap-starter/)

**Two oddities :**

- All of my select boxes appear to have the bootstrap `btn-danger` class on them.  I don't know why it has this as opposed to the `btn-default` class.
- At a certain break point the padding disappears for the options (as displayed, flushed up against the border).

**Code that enqueues the javascript and css:**

```
function my_scripts() {
  wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-select-css-cdn', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-select-css-cdn');

  wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-select-js-cdn', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js', null, null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-select-js-cdn');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

**For completeness** Here is my code for the select box:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
  <label for='order'>Order:</label><br>
  <select name='order' id='order' class="form-control">
    <option value='ASC'>ASC</option>
    <option value='DESC'>DESC</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And when I inspect the markup within the browser, here is what it shows:

[image: markup]

**So two questions:**

1. Why is this happening?  I highly doubt this is the default behavior.
2. How can I fix this?  How can I make the select boxes, site wide, be "btn-default" as opposed to "btn-danger".  Also: how can I add the padding back in for the options on the break point that it is disappearing?

Comment: Could you please provide related link of that?

Comment: @MinalChauhan unfortunately I do not have a link to the site because I am developing it locally on my computer.

Comment: Instead of used Dropdown just used Select for that..

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what you mean. I did not enter the `dropdown` class on the selectbox.  The bootstrap-select code must have automatically added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is bootstrap-select applies the `btn-light` class.  The issue was that the WP Bootstrap Starter Theme appears to have the `btn-light` class styled in an unexpected way.

The easiest, least invasive way I found to fix this was to do a find/replace in the bootstrap-select js file: find all instances of the text `btn-light` and replace it with `btn-default`.   As of right now, there was only one instance of the `btn-light` class being referenced in the js file, so it was very easy.

To fix the padding, I found the breakpoint where the padding was disappearing and added a rule to add it back in:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .dropdown-menu.inner.show{
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```